# Apache and or PHP Timeouts - Stumped.

Tags: php, linux, apache, timeout

I have a PHP script that when called via a browser it times-out after exactly 60 seconds. I have modified httpd.conf and set the Timeout directive to be 300. I have modified all PHP timeout settings to extend longer than 60 seconds. When I run the script from the command line it will complete. When I execute through browser each time after 60 seconds, POOF, timeout.

I have also checked for the existence of timeout directives in any of the .htaccess files. Nothing there.. I am completely stumped.

I am also forcing set_time_limit(0) within the PHP code.

I've been digging and testing for a week and have exhausted my knowledge. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was working on something that was a little slow, and in my loop I re-declared `set_time_limit(0)` .. for some reason that kept the script from timing out after that - it was quite odd.

Comment: made sure that both cases use the exactly same php.ini configuration?

Comment: Also if your using safe mode then you cant change max_execution_time

Comment: ouput `phpinfo()` and see what the `max_execution_time` is after setting the time limit

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you are setting a higher timeout limit both in PHP and in Apache.

If you set a high max_execution_time in php.ini your script won't timeout, however, if you are not flushing the output butter of the script's results to the browser on a regular basis, the script might time out on the Apache end due to a network timeout.

In httpd.conf do:

```
Timeout 216000
```

In php.ini do:

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

(setting it to 0 makes it never time out, like with a CLI (command line) script).

Make sure you restart Apache after you are done!  On most linux distro's you can do this by issuing the command (as root):

```
service httpd restart
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW, please note that using set_time_limit(0) on the script as per the suggestion below will only work if you php environment is not in safe mode.  You can check your php variables by running a script with phpinfo(); line on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous places that the maxtime can be set. If you are using FastCGI, especially though something such as Virtualmin, there are an additional set of settings for max_execution_time that are hidden to you unless you have access.

In short, you will need to figure out all the places, given your PHP stack setup, there can be an execution time limiter, up those values, restart the server, and then do

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

for good measure.

Without more information about your specific setup and given my experience in dealing with execution time hangups in PHP, that's the most I can tell you.